# How to return values between two timestamps in powerquery?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am trying to return values in a query between two UTC timestamps in Powerquery in Excel, but I cannot get the syntax correct, please can you advise?

I have had success by using the following code to return anything from a certain date, but this also includes any subsequent dates:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", 
    each [TimestampUTC] >= #datetime(pReadYear, pReadMonth, pReadDay, 0, 0, 0)
```

so I modified it to the following....

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", 
    each if [TimestampUTC] >= #datetime(pReadYear, pReadMonth, pReadDay, 0, 0, 0) 
        or [TimestampUTC] <= #datetime(pReadYear, pReadMonth, pReadDay+1, 0, 0, 0))
```

...but it keeps giving me a "Token Then Expected" error.  All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `if`, it expects it to be of the form:

```
if <condition> then <condition is true result> else <condition is false result>
```

I'm guessing what you want is a simple `and` (not an `or`) without the `if`.

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", 
    each [TimestampUTC] >= #datetime(pReadYear, pReadMonth, pReadDay, 0, 0, 0) 
        and [TimestampUTC] <= #datetime(pReadYear, pReadMonth, pReadDay+1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: thank you very much, that worked a treat.  Thanks for your time and the clarification.